# SQL statement using placeholder is not returning results

Tags: mysql

Having done this hundreds of times, I wrote a `SELECT` query like this:

```
$visitors = $wpdb->get_results( 
            $wpdb->prepare( 
    'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'visitors WHERE archive_this != %s',
     "checked"
    )
);
```

but it returned empty. So, I cheated and wrote it without the placeholder:

```
$visitors = $wpdb->get_results( 
    'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'visitors WHERE archive_this != "checked"',
);
```

which worked fine. But, I'd like the placeholder as best practices.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your `$wpdb->prepare()` syntax looks good, so did you actually pass `checked` to your actual `prepare()` code? If not, then maybe there were really no rows that matched the data for the `archive_this` column? And actually, if the query doesn't use dynamic values, then "cheating" is fine.. I.e. You don't have to use `prepare()`.. As long as the query itself is good (e.g. use `%%` instead of just `%` for literal percentage signs).

Comment: There are rows in the DB that would match (my "cheat" query pulls them up).

Comment: What's the full and actual code you used? Is it exactly the one (the 1st snippet) in the question? But try `$query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'visitors WHERE archive_this != %s', "checked" ); $visitors = $wpdb->get_results( $query ); var_dump( $visitors );` and check the dump output - is the array/`$visitors` really empty? 